# Is it possible to use a class from another CSS Module?

Tags: css-modules

Is it possible in one CSS Module to use a class from another CSS Module?

The problem is that CSS Modules is doing it's own class names translation and so `.class` from `A.css` will become `A-module--class-something` and `.class` from `B.css` will become `B-module--class--somethingElse` and they will be treated as separate classes.

### A.css

```css
.class {
  (...)
}
```

### B.css

```css
/* .class is the same class as in A.css */
.class > .someOtherClass {
}
```

Comment: Are you using React?

Answer (score 5):

What I was able to do is to "import" the other class like such

```css
@value someClass from "./xxx.module.css";
```

and then reference it like that:

```css
:global(.someClass) .myClass {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming A and B are both CSS files, if you link to both of them (in the head), they will both operate as normal.

It is important to note that if they say conflicting information (they are targeting the same style attribute) one of the styles will not be applied (it will get crossed out when looking at the development tools). You can get past this problem by using the !important keyword on your styles. But use this keyword sparingly as it is not considered a best practice.

As you can see in the below snip, it chooses one to use. The file names can be seen on the right.

[image]

Comment: I think they won't work out of the box, because of the translation of class names that CSS Modules is doing. `.class` from `A.css` won't be `.class` but `A-module--class--something`, while .class` in `B.css` will be translated to `B-module--class--somethingElse`. And so those will be treated as different classes.

Comment: updated my post with how brave (chromium based browser) renders from two different files.

Comment: What bothers me in your example is that the class name `.background` is not translated - doesn't have any prefixes nor suffixes. The way CSS Modules is configured for me, when I write class `.background` in my stylesheet, in HTML it'll be applied as `A-module--background--someHash`, not as `.background`. Why is it like this in your example?

Comment: Do you mean like -webkit- and such (vendor prefixes)?

Comment: No, I don't mean vendor prefixes. I think you are missing that I'm using CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), not just standard CSS. CSS Modules is translating all class names on build-time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like this?

### A.css

```
.class {
  /* rule-set */
}
```

### B.css

```
@import "A.css"
.class > .someOtherClass {
  /* rule-set */
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious if this works, because you don't relate in any way `.class` to be from `A.css`. Let me try...

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work. `.class` in `B.css` is still treated as different class to `.class` from `A.css`, because of the class names translation CSS Modules apply.

Comment: The problem is that I believe CSS Modules were made to keep classes in local files, so I don't think there is a way.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I wanted to make sure it's not possible.

Comment: It's possible to reference class from other files when composing: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#composing-from-other-files, so I thought maybe it's possible also in other places.

Comment: Seems it's not possible: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/342

Comment: Try this: https://bambielli.com/til/2017-08-11-css-modules-composes/

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what I need to do, because composing includes/copies the styles of the composed class. I don't want to include the styles of `.class`, I only want to use `.class` in a selector, to conditionally apply other styles.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it seems there is no direct way to reference a class name.

So I figured out a possible solution:

## B.css

```
:global(.class) > .someOtherClass {
  /* rule-set */
}
```

Then apply class in your html, and after processing, it will be converted like this:

```
<div class="class A-module--class--something">
    <div class="B-module--class--somethingElse">
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, you keep `A-module--class--something` rule (which won't collide ever) and a "class" reference for more complex rules. Not the best solution since you need to modify your html code, but it will minimize css polluted workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add hover for class in another module
this is my solution:

I imported the class who needed hover:

```
@value bage from './BageList/RecBage/styles.module.css';
```

and added hover:

```
.recommendCart:hover .bage:global {

}
```

`.recommendCart`- classname in my first module
`.bage`  - classname in my second module